# How do I make my code find out which button was pressed within a reasonable amount of time?

Tags: java, swing, awt

Alright, this one is a bit of a doozy, its about 240 lines long, but on to my point. The point is that it doesn't work. I'm pretty new to coding in general and some help would be really appreciated. I know where the problem is, it's in the last bits of it in the for loops, I went under the false presumption that if you click a JButton, it is then selected. How do I implement the .setSelected method to my program without rewriting the entire code? This code is a make-shift jeopardy of sorts btw.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import sun.audio.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Jeopardy implements ActionListener
{
    public static JFrame frame = new JFrame("Jeopardy!");
    public static JButton[] row1Buttons = new JButton[6];
    public static JButton[] row2Buttons = new JButton[6];
    public static JButton[] row3Buttons = new JButton[6];
    public static JButton[] row4Buttons = new JButton[6];
    public static JButton[] row5Buttons = new JButton[6];

    //Creates 5 arrays, each with 6 JButtons in each (otherwise mass confusion
    //is going to ensue because I would have to individually add 30 JButtons to the pane,
    //all of which I would have to remember what they contain.)
    public static JPanel pane = new JPanel();
    public static JLabel[] labels = new JLabel[6];
    //Creates an array of 6 JLabels
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.toFront();
        frame.setContentPane(pane);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Font font = new Font("ComicSans", Font.PLAIN, 20);
        Color colour = new Color(0, 0, 240);
        for(int a = 0; a < row1Buttons.length; a++)
        {
            row1Buttons[a] = new JButton("$200");
            row2Buttons[a] = new JButton("$400");
            row3Buttons[a] = new JButton("$600");
            row4Buttons[a] = new JButton("$800");
            row5Buttons[a] = new JButton("$1000");
            //Gives text to all 30 JButtons
            row1Buttons[a].addActionListener(new Jeopardy());
            row2Buttons[a].addActionListener(new Jeopardy());
            row3Buttons[a].addActionListener(new Jeopardy());
            row4Buttons[a].addActionListener(new Jeopardy());
            row5Buttons[a].addActionListener(new Jeopardy());
            //adds action listener to all 30
            row1Buttons[a].setBackground(colour);
            row2Buttons[a].setBackground(colour);
            row3Buttons[a].setBackground(colour);
            row4Buttons[a].setBackground(colour);
            row5Buttons[a].setBackground(colour);
            //sets background colour
            row1Buttons[a].setForeground(Color.yellow);
            row2Buttons[a].setForeground(Color.yellow);
            row3Buttons[a].setForeground(Color.yellow);
            row4Buttons[a].setForeground(Color.yellow);
            row5Buttons[a].setForeground(Color.yellow);
        }
        labels[0] = new JLabel("Mathematics");
        labels[1] = new JLabel("Computer Science");
        labels[2] = new JLabel("Historical Events");
        labels[3] = new JLabel("Chemistry");
        labels[4] = new JLabel("TBD");
        labels[5] = new JLabel("TBD");
        for(int k = 0; k < labels.length; k++)
        {
            labels[k].setForeground(Color.yellow);
        }
        pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(6, 6, 6, 6));
        for(int b = 0; b < labels.length; b++)
        {
            pane.add(labels[b]);
            pane.add(row1Buttons[b]);
            pane.add(row2Buttons[b]);
            pane.add(row3Buttons[b]);
            pane.add(row4Buttons[b]);
            pane.add(row5Buttons[b]);
        }
        pane.setBackground(Color.blue);
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {
        String[] answerRow1 = new String[6];
        String[] answerRow2 = new String[6];
        String[] answerRow3 = new String[6];
        String[] answerRow4 = new String[6];
        String[] answerRow5 = new String[6];
        String[] questionsRow1 = new String[6];
        //Write $200 questions
        questionsRow1[0] = "Question";
        questionsRow1[1] = "Question";
        questionsRow1[2] = "Question";
        questionsRow1[3] = "Question";
        questionsRow1[4] = "Question";
        questionsRow1[5] = "Question";
        String[] questionsRow2 = new String[6];
        //Write $400 questions
        questionsRow2[0] = "Question";
        questionsRow2[1] = "Question";
        questionsRow2[2] = "Question";
        questionsRow2[3] = "Question";
        questionsRow2[4] = "Question";
        questionsRow2[5] = "Question";
        String[] questionsRow3 = new String[6];
        //Write $600 questions
        questionsRow3[0] = ("The function y=3(2)^x will have this for a y value when x = 3.");
        questionsRow3[1] = "Question";
        questionsRow3[2] = "Question";
        questionsRow3[3] = "Question";
        questionsRow3[4] = "Question";
        questionsRow3[5] = "Question";
        String[] questionsRow4 = new String[6];
        //Write $800 questions
        questionsRow4[0] = "Question";
        questionsRow4[1] = "Question";
        questionsRow4[2] = "Question";
        questionsRow4[3] = "Question";
        questionsRow4[4] = "Question";
        questionsRow4[5] = "Question";
        String[] questionsRow5 = new String[6];
        //Write $1000 questions
        questionsRow5[0] = "Question";
        questionsRow5[1] = "Question";
        questionsRow5[2] = "Question";
        questionsRow5[3] = "Question";
        questionsRow5[4] = "Question";
        questionsRow5[5] = "Question";
        for(int j = 0; j < questionsRow1.length; j++)
        {
            if(row1Buttons[j].getModel().isPressed())
            {
                try
                {
                    InputStream in = new FileInputStream("sounds/x.wav");
                    AudioStream openSound = new AudioStream(in);
                    AudioPlayer.player.start(openSound);

                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You don't have the sound clip for this");
                }
                answerRow1[j] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, questionsRow1[j]);
            }
        }
        for(int a = 0; a < questionsRow2.length; a++)
        {
            if(row2Buttons[a].isSelected())
            {
                try
                {
                    InputStream in = new FileInputStream("sounds/x.wav");
                    AudioStream openSound = new AudioStream(in);
                    AudioPlayer.player.start(openSound);
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You don't have the sound clip for this");
                }    
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, questionsRow2[a]);
            }
        }
        for(int r = 0; r < questionsRow3.length; r++)
        {
            if(row3Buttons[r].isSelected())
            {
                try
                {
                    InputStream in = new FileInputStream("sounds/x.wav");
                    AudioStream openSound = new AudioStream(in);
                    AudioPlayer.player.start(openSound);
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You don't have the sound clip for this");
                }
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, questionsRow3[r]);
            }
        }
        for(int e = 0; e < questionsRow4.length; e++)
        {
            if(row4Buttons[e].isSelected())
            {
                try
                {
                    InputStream in = new FileInputStream("sounds/x.wav");
                    AudioStream openSound = new AudioStream(in);
                    AudioPlayer.player.start(openSound);
                }
                catch(Exception exception)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You don't have the sound clip for this");
                }    
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, questionsRow4[e]);
            }
        }
        for(int d = 0; d < questionsRow5.length; d++)
        {
            if(row5Buttons[d].isSelected())
            {
                try
                {
                    InputStream in = new FileInputStream("sounds/x.wav");
                    AudioStream openSound = new AudioStream(in);
                    AudioPlayer.player.start(openSound);
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You don't have the sound clip for this");
                }
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, questionsRow5[d]);
            }
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: Use the `Action` API; Use some kind of `Map` look up...

Comment: And you'll want to use for loops to greatly reduce redundancy (which your code has a **lot** of) which will make your code much easier to debug and enhance.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on codereview.

Comment: Thanks, I realize it has a lot of repitition, try reading it over again, I used for loops all over the place.

Comment: Would you be able to scale this back to a small, self-contained example?  If you know where the problem is, then please don't make everyone read through a program of this size.  Just the minimum amount of code that you need, in order to exhibit your actual question, would be fine, thank you.

Comment: 1) Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread).  The GUI will 'freeze' when that happens.  See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for details and the fix. 2) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: `import sun.audio.*;`  Don't use the `sun` packages.  1) They will not be on a JVM made by a different manufacturer. 2) They might not be in Oracle's next JVM. 3) We've had better ways to play audio since Java 1.3.  See the `Clip` from [Java Sound](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info).  A `Clip` has its own thread, so playing it will not block the EDT.  The loading might though, and that should be done just once when the app. starts up.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you make the frame visible and then add your components. Instead, call `setVisible()` at the *end* of your constructor, *after* you `pack()` the frame.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ...
    pane.setBackground(Color.blue);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: No, that doesn't fix it actually. Ill post below what did.

Answer (score 0):

try to create a new class for buttons

```
public class Response_Button extends JButton {

public Response_Button(final JPanel container, final String name) {
    this.setText(name);
    this.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(container, "clicked " + name);
        }
    });
}
```

like this each button will respond through it's own method

Comment: Or use an `Action` or create a custom `ActionListener` class and attach it to an instance of a `JButton`, hardly any need to extend a `JButton` - considering you're not actually adding any new functionality to the class and are, instead, locking yourself into a particular class...not really a good solution - IMHO

Answer (score 0):

This is what fixes it:

```
if(event.getSource()== row1Buttons[j])
```

Yes, that makes it so that it will do all of the category in one fell swoop, but it doesn't matter. Thanks for all who tried and gave positive and helpful answers.
EDIT: nope, it doesn't do it all in one go, I just labeled it wrong.